# How to convert minutes into months, days and minutes with a high precision?

Tags: unit-of-measure, rounding-unit

I'm  want to do a time convertion, and I' facing a precision problem.
I'have the time in minutes, and I want to change it into
Months, days, hours, and minutes formant
I've did a table in excel to test my logic with the following example:
I have `110008.128 minutes` which should be:
`(2 months) + (15 days) + (12 hours) + (30 minutes)`

The logic that I'm using is:

1. Convert the minutes to months : `year= minutes * (30.417*24*60)` the `30.417` is for precision
2. get the decimal result in `year` and : `days = (year-int(year)) * 30.417`
3. get the decimal result in `days` and : `hours = (days-int(days)) * 24`
4. get the decimal result in `hours` and : `minutes = (hours-int(hours)) * 60`

The result is getting

`2.5115735717965` Months,  `15.560533` days,    `13.453` hours   `27.17` minutes
geting just the integer part  `2` mon `15` days `13` hours and `27` minutes which is wrong.

Someone knows what is happening ?

Thanks a lot guys

Comment: How do you define a month? Does it have 28, 29, 30 or 31 days? Is this the 30.417 in your formulas? But if you calculate between 30 January and 2 Mars 2020, you will not have the same time as if you calculate between the 2 same dates in 2021?

Comment: I'm assuming that the month is 30, and the 30.417 I've put it because it was used in Google's calculator, and it was saing that was for precision.